# nginx server sees its own ip instead of reverse proxy ip

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two severs, one is an app server and another is a reverse proxy.

user -> proxy server -> app server

When a user comes from proxy server, I will check the ip and if the ip is from the proxy server the user is logged in automatically.

proxy server config

```
server {
    ...
    location / { 
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_pass http://app.server.com;
    }   
}
```

app server config

```
server {
    ...
    # rewrite request
    rewrite ^/request/(.*)$ /request.php?uri=$uri last;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffer_size        128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size  256k;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    backend;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Basically, all requests to the proxy are passed to the app server. Assuming that my app server ip is 5.6.7.8, and proxy ip is 1.2.3.4. When I open the proxy server in chrome, the chrome debug tool shows the proxy ip address in Remote Address(1.2.3.4) of Header's General section. However, when I try to access the ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], it gives the ip addess of app server itself(5.6.7.8).

I have tried these configs, but the remote address still showed the app server's ip and the X-Forwarded-For for real client ip which was not what I wanted.

```
proxy_set_header HOST $host; <- this makes proxy server always responds with 404
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

What do I have to do to get the proxy ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or other fields?

---

My prebuilt nginx does not have the module, so I built one myself.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.7
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_sub_module
```

Now the proxy server config looks like

```
server {
    ...
    location / { 
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
        real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on; 
        proxy_pass http://app.server.com;
    }   
}
```

But the issue remains, the app server still gets its own ip address.

---

Test the real_ip_header config on app server

app server config

```
sever {
    ...
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on; 

    # rewrite api 
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /route.php?uri=$uri last;

    location @rewrite {

        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffer_size        128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size  256k;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    backend;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
}
```

proxy server config

```
server {
    listen       1000;
    server_name  my.proxy.com;

    charset      utf-8;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location / {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_pass http://app.server.com;
    }
}
```

The issue remains.

---

My proxy config ends up like this, and I get proxy server ip from **X-Forwarded-For** now

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://app.server.com;
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ngx_http_realip_module` module - it is used to change the client address to the one sent in the specified header field.

Example:

```
# Set the client remote address to the one sent in the X_FORWARDED_FOR header from trusted addresses.
set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.2.1;
set_real_ip_from  2001:0db8::/32;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

---

I presume that you'd still want to know the real client's IP address, and the IP address of the proxy server.

Proxy server

Add a custom header; `REVERSE-VIA` to include proxy server's address. This allows the app server to read `REVERSE-VIA` header for the IP address.

```
server {
    listen       1000;
    server_name  my.proxy.com;

    charset      utf-8;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location / {
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        proxy_pass http://app.server.com;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  REVERSE-VIA       $server_addr;
    }
}
```

App server

```
server {
    ...
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on; 

    # rewrite api 
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /route.php?uri=$uri last;

    location @rewrite {

        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffer_size        128k;
        fastcgi_buffers            256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size  256k;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    backend;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but still I got the same app server ip. Is there anything wrong about my config? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you "reload/restart" ?

Comment: Well, I did... Anyway, in case I was a real dumb i just did it again. No, still not working.

Comment: Move the real_ip_header to app server. reload both nginx. Still, no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the updated config. In this case, I do see the `X-Forwarded-For`, but it gives the `real client ip` instead of the `proxy server ip` and the same for `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: Tried the `proxy_set_header  REVERSE-VIA       $server_addr;`, but it showed nothing. I also tried to use  add_header REVERSE-VIA like what you did. But it gives local ip address like 192.168.100.123.

Comment: Is that the IP of the proxy server? If it is, then it is correct.

Comment: No, that is not the real ip address of the proxy server. I tested that on both a in house docker machine and public could server, it only showed the private ip instead of public ip. In my case, I need to identify the public ip.

Comment: You may want to check out the Nginx embedded variable and whether the values are what are you expecting - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: Late to the party, but nginx doesn't seem to reload the values of `set_real_ip_from` unless you do a full restart.